# trac notification not sending emails

Tags: apache, notifications, ldap, centos, trac

I am trying to set up trac notification but it is not working. In apache i have

```
<LocationMatch "/trac/[^/]+/login">
        AuthType Kerberos
        AuthName KerberosLogin
        KrbServiceName HTTP/intranet.domain.com
        KrbMethodNegotiate On
        KrbMethodK5Passwd On
        KrbAuthRealms DOMAIN.COM
        Krb5KeyTab /etc/httpd/conf/intranet.keytab
        require valid-user
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</LocationMatch>
```

In trac.ini I have

```
always_notify_owner = true
always_notify_reporter = true
always_notify_updater = true
mime_encoding = base64
smtp_always_bcc =
smtp_always_cc = first.last@domain.com
smtp_default_domain = domain.com
smtp_enabled = true
smtp_from = trac@domain.com
smtp_password =
smtp_port = 25
smtp_replyto = support@domain.com
smtp_server = hero.uk.domain.com
smtp_subject_prefix = __default__
smtp_user =
use_public_cc = false
use_short_addr = false
use_tls = false
ignore_domains = domain.com
```

Problem is I log in as firstl@domain.com but my email is first.last@domain.com. how do i fix this?

I put my email address under settings however when i create a new ticket In the log file i get

```
2013-11-29 12:40:34,804 Trac[notification] DEBUG: Sending SMTP notification to hero.uk.domain.com on port 25 to [u'firstl@DOMAIN.COM', u'somebody@domain.com', u'first.last@domain.com']
```

**UPDATE**

I have installed Announcer plugin. Error I recieve

```
Dec  4 10:48:43 hero Trac[paradox:api] INFO: Synchronized '(default)' repository in 0.00 seconds
Dec  4 10:48:45 hero mountd[2510]: authenticated mount request from buzz.uk.domain.com:960 for /data/apps (/data/apps)
Dec  4 10:48:51 hero Trac[paradox:api] INFO: Synchronized '(default)' repository in 0.00 seconds
Dec  4 10:49:26 hero Trac[paradox:env] INFO: -------------------------------- environment startup [Trac 0.12.5] --------------------------------
Dec  4 10:49:27 hero Trac[paradox:loader] ERROR: Skipping "announcer.email_decorators = announcer.email_decorators":  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12.5-py2.4.egg/trac/loader.py", line 68, in _load_eggs     entry.load(require=True)   File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.4.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 1954, in load     entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])   File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/TracAnnouncer-1.0dev_r12503-py2.4.egg/announcer/email_decorators.py", line 7, in ?     from email.utils import parseaddr ImportError: No module named utils
Dec  4 10:49:27 hero Trac[paradox:api] INFO: Synchronized '(default)' repository in 0.06 seconds
Dec  4 10:49:27 hero Trac[paradox:api] ERROR: AnnouncementSystem failed. Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/TracAnnouncer-1.0dev_r12503-py2.4.egg/announcer/api.py", line 560, in _real_send     subscriptions = self.resolver.subscriptions(evt)   File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/TracAnnouncer-1.0dev_r12503-py2.4.egg/announcer/api.py", line 311, in subscriptions     ordered_subs = sorted(subscriptions, key=itemgetter(1,2,3,6)) TypeError: itemgetter expected 1 arguments, got 4
Dec  4 10:49:27 hero Trac[paradox:api] INFO: Synchronized '(default)' repository in 0.00 seconds
```

Configuration

```
[announcer]
admit_domains =
always_notify_owner = true
always_notify_reporter = true
always_notify_updater = true
default_email_format = text/html
email_address_resolvers = SpecifiedEmailResolver, SessionEmailResolver
email_sender = SmtpEmailSender
ignore_domains =
mime_encoding = none
notify_on_failed_build = true
notify_on_successful_build = false
smtp_always_bcc =
smtp_always_cc = sharif.uddin@domain.com
smtp_default_domain =
smtp_enabled = true
smtp_from = trac@domain.com
smtp_from_name = Trac
smtp_password =
smtp_port = 25
smtp_replyto = sharif.uddin@domain.com
smtp_server = hero.uk.domain.com
smtp_subject_prefix = __default__
smtp_user =
ticket_subject_template = $prefix #$ticket.id: $summary
use_public_cc = False
use_short_addr = false
use_tls = false
```

New UPDATE

current conf file `/usr/share/trac/conf`

```
[root@hero trac]# cat /usr/share/trac/conf/trac.ini 
[announcer]
admit_domains =
always_notify_component_owner = true
always_notify_owner = true
always_notify_reporter = true
always_notify_updater = true
default_email_format = text/html
email_address_resolvers = SpecifiedEmailResolver, SessionEmailResolver
ignore_domains =
#mime_encoding = base64
smtp_always_bcc =
smtp_always_cc =
smtp_default_domain =
smtp_enabled = true
smtp_from = trac-no-reply@domain.com
smtp_from_name = Trac
smtp_password =
smtp_port = 25
smtp_replyto = no-reply@domain.com
smtp_server = hero
smtp_subject_prefix = __default__
smtp_timeout = 30
smtp_user =
ticket_email_header_fields = owner, reporter, milestone, component, priority, severity.
ticket_email_subject = Ticket #${ticket.id}: ${ticket['summary']}.
ticket_subject_template = $prefix $ticket.id: $summary
use_public_cc = false
use_short_addr = false
use_tls = false
email_enabled = true


#[notification]
#always_notify_owner = false
#always_notify_reporter = true
#always_notify_updater = true
#mime_encoding = base64
#smtp_always_bcc =
#smtp_always_cc = 
#smtp_default_domain = domain.com
#smtp_enabled = true
#smtp_from = trac@domain.com
#smtp_password =
#smtp_port = 25
#smtp_replyto = support@domain.com
#smtp_server = hero.uk.domain.com
#smtp_subject_prefix = __default__
#smtp_user =
#use_public_cc = false
#use_short_addr = false
#use_tls = false
#ignore_domains = domain.com


[ldap]
enable = true
global_perms = true
host = echo
basedn = dc=domain,dc=com
user_rdn = ou=sites
group_rdn = cn=users
store_bind = true
bind_user = cn=Administrator,cn=users,dc=domain,dc=com
bind_passwd = woki1141



[trac]
base_url = http://intranet/trac/
#permission_store = LdapPermissionStore


[logging]
log_format = Trac[$(basename)s:$(module)s] $(levelname)s: $(message)s
log_type = syslog
log_level = DEBUG

[components]
webadmin.* = enabled
#ldapauth.* = enabled
#ldapplugin.* = enabled
#ldapplugin.api.ldappermissiongroupprovider = enabled
#ldapplugin.api.ldappermissionstore = disabled
ticketdelete.* = enabled
tracopt.ticket.deleter = enabled
tracwysiwyg.* = enabled
announcer.* = enabled
#announcer.api.announcementsystem = enabled
#announcer.distributors.mail.emaildistributor = enabled
#announcer.formatters.ticket.ticketformatter = enabled
#announcer.formatters.wiki.wikiformatter = enabled
#announcer.pref.announcerpreferences = enabled
#announcer.producers.attachment.attachmentchangeproducer = enabled
#announcer.producers.ticket.ticketchangeproducer = enabled
#announcer.producers.wiki.wikichangeproducer = enabled
#announcer.resolvers.sessionemail.sessionemailresolver = enabled
#announcer.subscribers.ticket_compat.carboncopysubscriber = enabled
#announcer.subscribers.ticket_compat.legacyticketsubscriber = enabled
#announcer.subscribers.ticket_components.ticketcomponentsubscriber = enabled
#announcer.subscribers.ticket_custom.ticketcustomfieldsubscriber = enabled
#announcer.subscribers.watch_users.userchangesubscriber = enabled
#announcer.subscribers.watchers.watchsubscriber = enabled
```

What appears in log file when creating a ticket.

```
==> /data/intranet/html/trac/paradox/log/trac.log <==
Trac[paradox:env] INFO: Reloading environment due to configuration change
Trac[paradox:env] INFO: -------------------------------- environment startup [Trac 0.12.5] --------------------------------
```

...

```
Trac[paradox:default_workflow] DEBUG: Workflow actions at initialization: {u'resolve': {u'operations': [u'set_resolution'], 'name': u'resolve', 'default': 0, 'newstate': u'closed', 'oldstates': [u'new', u'assigned', u'reopened'], u'permissions': [u'TICKET_MODIFY']}, u'accept': {u'operations': [u'set_owner_to_self'], 'name': u'accept', 'default': 0, 'newstate': u'assigned', 'oldstates': [u'new'], u'permissions': [u'TICKET_MODIFY']}, u'leave': {u'operations': [u'leave_status'], 'name': u'leave', u'default': 1, 'newstate': u'*', 'oldstates': [u'*'], 'permissions': []}, u'reopen': {u'operations': [u'del_resolution'], 'name': u'reopen', 'default': 0, 'newstate': u'reopened', 'oldstates': [u'closed'], u'permissions': [u'TICKET_CREATE']}, u'reassign': {u'operations': [u'set_owner'], 'name': u'reassign', 'default': 0, 'newstate': u'new', 'oldstates': [u'new', u'assigned', u'reopened'], u'permissions': [u'TICKET_MODIFY']}, '_reset': {'operations': ['reset_workflow'], 'name': 'reset', 'default': 0, 'newstate': 'new', 'oldstates': [], 'permissions': []}}

Trac[paradox:main] DEBUG: Dispatching <Request "GET '/chrome/common/desc.png'">
Trac[paradox:main] DEBUG: Dispatching <Request "GET '/chrome/tracwysiwyg/editor.css'">
Trac[paradox:main] DEBUG: Dispatching <Request "POST '/newticket'">
Trac[paradox:svn_fs] DEBUG: Subversion bindings imported
Trac[paradox:api] INFO: Synchronized '(default)' repository in 0.06 seconds
Trac[paradox:session] DEBUG: Retrieving session for ID 'sharifu@DOMAIN.COM'
Trac[paradox:api] DEBUG: action controllers for ticket workflow: ['ConfigurableTicketWorkflow']
Trac[paradox:api] DEBUG: Adding (None [0]) for 'always' on rule (TicketComponentOwnerSubscriber) for (email)
Trac[paradox:api] DEBUG: Adding (None [0]) for 'always' on rule (TicketReporterSubscriber) for (email)
Trac[paradox:filters] DEBUG: Checking *_VIEW permission on event for resource ticket:33
Trac[paradox:filters] DEBUG: Checking *_VIEW permission on event for resource ticket:33
Trac[paradox:api] DEBUG: AnnouncementSystem has found the following subscriptions: [sharifu@DOMAIN.COM(not authenticated) via email], [sharif.uddin@domain.com(not authenticated) via email]
Trac[paradox:mail] DEBUG: EmailDistributor has found the following formats capable of handling 'email' of 'ticket': text/html, text/plain
Trac[paradox:mail] DEBUG: EmailDistributor found the address 'sharifu@DOMAIN.COM' for 'None (not authenticated)' via: NoneType
Trac[paradox:mail] DEBUG: EmailDistributor expected local delivery for None to: sharifu@DOMAIN.COM
Trac[paradox:mail] DEBUG: EmailDistributor found the address 'sharif.uddin@domain.com' for 'None (not authenticated)' via: NoneType
Trac[paradox:mail] DEBUG: EmailDistributor expected local delivery for None to: sharif.uddin@domain.com
Trac[paradox:mail] DEBUG: EmailDistributor is sending event as 'text/html' to: sharifu@DOMAIN.COM, sharif.uddin@domain.com
Trac[paradox:mail] DEBUG: All email recipients: [u'sharifu@DOMAIN.COM', u'sharif.uddin@domain.com']
Trac[paradox:mail] DEBUG: EmailDistributor took 0.43 seconds to send.
Trac[paradox:api] DEBUG: AnnouncementSystem sent event in 0.65 seconds.
Trac[paradox:main] DEBUG: Dispatching <Request "GET '/ticket/33'">

==> /var/log/maillog <==
Dec  5 10:26:07 hero sendmail[9041]: rB5AQ7cu009041: from=<trac@localhost>, size=7715, class=-60, nrcpts=2, msgid=<NB2HI4B2F4XWS3TUOJQW4ZLUF52HEYLDFR2GSY3LMV2CYMZT@localhost>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA, relay=localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1]
Dec  5 10:26:08 hero sendmail[9043]: STARTTLS=client, relay=thor.uk.domain.com., version=TLSv1/SSLv3, verify=FAIL, cipher=AES128-SHA, bits=128/128

==> /data/intranet/html/trac/paradox/log/trac.log <==
Trac[paradox:api] INFO: Synchronized '(default)' repository in 0.00 seconds
Trac[paradox:session] DEBUG: Retrieving session for ID 'sharifu@DOMAIN.COM'
Trac[paradox:default_workflow] DEBUG: render_ticket_action_control: action "leave"
Trac[paradox:default_workflow] DEBUG: render_ticket_action_control: action "resolve"
Trac[paradox:default_workflow] DEBUG: render_ticket_action_control: action "reassign"
Trac[paradox:default_workflow] DEBUG: render_ticket_action_control: action "accept"
Trac[paradox:chrome] DEBUG: Prepare chrome data for request

==> /var/log/maillog <==
Dec  5 10:26:08 hero sendmail[9043]: rB5AQ7cu009041: to=<sharif.uddin@domain.com>,<sharifu@DOMAIN.COM>, delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=265715, relay=thor.uk.domain.com. [172.16.0.19], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (<NB2HI4B2F4XWS3TUOJQW4ZLUF52HEYLDFR2GSY3LMV2CYMZT@localhost> [InternalId=6859757] Queued mail for delivery)

==> /data/intranet/html/trac/paradox/log/trac.log <==
Trac[paradox:main] DEBUG: Dispatching <Request "GET '/chrome/common/js/auto_preview.js'">
Trac[paradox:main] DEBUG: Dispatching <Request "GET '/chrome/common/feed.png'">
Trac[paradox:main] DEBUG: Dispatching <Request "GET '/chrome/common/draft.png'">
```

Note on Admin->Components I have set the owner to legitimate email address.

Comment: If you add an email address to the CC field, does the user receive the email? You should first make sure that Trac can send email using your SMTP server.

Comment: trac can send email. the person in the cc field receives the email, but the person who creates the ticket or updates ticket does not even when their email is entered under settings tab. also where does `somebody@domain.com` come from?

Answer (score 1):

> I put my email address under settings however when i create a new ticket In the log file i get ...

I tried this on Trac 1.0-stable, and the email address that is set through the user preferences (`/prefs`) and stored in the session data [is used](http://trac.edgewall.org/browser/tags/trac-1.0.1/trac/notification.py?marks=380-381#L366) even when the username is an email address. This behavior was implemented in [#8356](http://trac.edgewall.org/ticket/8356) for Trac 1.0, so it looks like you may need to upgrade to resolve the issue.

> ... also where does somebody@domain.com come from?

If `[ticket] default_owner = < default >`, then new tickets will be assigned to the component owner. The owner for `component1` and `component2` in the initial data that is provided with Trac is `somebody`. The default domain (`[notification] smtp_default_domain`) is [appended](http://trac.edgewall.org/browser/tags/trac-1.0.1/trac/notification.py?marks=385-390#L366) to usernames that don't have an email address set in the session data. If you remove `smtp_default_domain` or set its value to empty, you should see in the logs: `Trac[notification] INFO: Email address w/o domain: somebody`, and email won't be sent to `somebody@domain.com`.

Comment: I cannot upgrade as i am on centos 5 and 1.0 requires python 2.5+. i have made `[notification] smtp_default_domain` blank and it has removed the `somebody` but i still cannot seem to set up the email. I have upgraded to 0.12 is there any way to map AD username to email?

Comment: You might try using the [AnnouncerPlugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/AnnouncerPlugin) to see if it fixes you issue. Finding some way to get Python 2.5 or higher installed on your server is the route that I would take though.

Comment: See [trachacks:#11432](https://trac-hacks.org/ticket/11432). I'll try to get the package updated shortly.

Comment: not sure what i am meant to update exactly? which file? i don't want to break my production server. i have updated question shortly

Comment: You either need to patch the source and reinstall the plugin, or wait for the plugin maintainers to patch it.

Comment: so i need to patch announcer plugin? i follow the link above, which file do i patch and wheres the patch file?